# how to modify the output

Tags: python, string, list, output

```
def noalpha(s):

    noa = ''
    for c in s:
        if not (c in noa or c.isalpha()):
            noa += c
    return noa

def flines(t, ww):

    s=noalpha(t)
    lines=t.lower().splitlines()
    lst=[]
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for caratteri in s:
            lines[i]=lines[i].replace(caratteri, ' ')
        wrdst=lines[i].split()
        l= 'Line ' +str(i)+': ' 
        False
        for k in ww:
            k=k.lower()
            num=wrdst.count(k)

            if num>0:
                l+='"'+ str(k) + '"=' + str(num)+' '
                True
        if True:
            lst+=[l]


    return lst
```

can someone explain to me how i can modify the output so that the empty lines do not appear? the output i get after running the program is:

```
['Line 0: "to"=1 ', 'Line 1: "the"=1 ', 'Line 2: "the"=1 ', 'Line 3: "to"=1 ', 'Line 4: "so"=2 ', 'Line 5: ', 'Line 6: ', 'Line 7: "to"=1 "the"=1 ', 'Line 8: "to"=1 "the"=2 ', 'Line 9: ', 'Line 10: ', 'Line 11: "to"=1 "the"=1 ', 'Line 12: ', 'Line 13: ', 'Line 14: "so"=1 ', 'Line 15: "to"=1 ', 'Line 16: ', 'Line 17: ', 'Line 18: "to"=1 "the"=2 ', 'Line 19: "the"=1 ', 'Line 20: "the"=4 ', 'Line 21: ', 'Line 22: ', 'Line 23: ', 'Line 24: ', 'Line 25: ', 'Line 26: ', 'Line 27: "the"=1 ', 'Line 28: ', 'Line 29: ', 'Line 30: "the"=1 ', 'Line 31: ']
```

Comment: Erm, why is there a `False` and `True` just standing there out of nowhere?

Comment: so that it fills the list only whe  the loops are true

Comment: The code like this works only it prints out the lines where there are no words of the parameter ww

Comment: Games Braniac what do you mean?

Comment: Some example in/output?

Comment: output:['Line 0: "to"=1 ',
 'Line 1: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 2: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 3: "to"=1 ',
 'Line 4: "so"=2 ',
 'Line 5: ',
 'Line 6: ',
 'Line 7: "to"=1 "the"=1 ',
 'Line 8: "to"=1 "the"=2 ',
 'Line 9: ',
 'Line 10: ',
 'Line 11: "to"=1 "the"=1 ',
 'Line 12: ',
 'Line 13: ',
 'Line 14: "so"=1 ',
 'Line 15: "to"=1 ',
 'Line 16: ',
 'Line 17: ',
 'Line 18: "to"=1 "the"=2 ',
 'Line 19: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 20: "the"=4 ',
 'Line 21: ',
 'Line 22: ',
 'Line 23: ',
 'Line 24: ',
 'Line 25: ',
 'Line 26: ',
 'Line 27: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 28: ',
 'Line 29: ',
 'Line 30: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 31: ']

Comment: the input is too long but it's basically a string file and a list of words ['alice','the','to']

Comment: Show the input text also

Comment: I started downvoting too, because it is a mess. Where is the input??? Where is that part of your code which creates the output? Honestly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this code is not pretty to do what your're looking to do you need to change these lines

```
if num>0:
    l+='"'+ str(k) + '"=' + str(num)+' '
    True
if True:
    lst+=[l]
```

If you change it to something like

```
if num>0:
    l+='"'+ str(k) + '"=' + str(num)+' '
    flag = True
if flag:
    lst+=[l]
```

and then if you reinitialize the flag = False at the beginning of the for loop it should produce the results you want.  by doing the if True you are saying to always append to the list vs when there is actually something in there

Comment: YES this works perfectly could you explain why you have to attribute true and false to a variable? Also another minor problem in my output is that it prints it on different lines:['Line 0: "to"=1 ',
 'Line 1: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 2: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 3: "to"=1 ',
 'Line 4: "so"=2 ',
 'Line 7: "to"=1 "the"=1 ',
 'Line 8: "to"=1 "the"=2 ',
 'Line 11: "to"=1 "the"=1 ',
 'Line 14: "so"=1 ',
 'Line 15: "to"=1 ',
 'Line 18: "to"=1 "the"=2 ',
 'Line 19: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 20: "the"=4 ',
 'Line 27: "the"=1 ',
 'Line 30: "the"=1 ']

Comment: So True will always evaluate to true I edited my answer to reflect that. Unsure what you mean my it prints on different lines please elaborate

Comment: okay thank you very much, and nevermind i solved that issue